# Post failing in a REST api

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jersey

This is my person object.

```
persons
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| given_name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| family_name | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Here's the method that does the posting,




 public static void addPerson(Person person) {
            String givenName = person.getGivenName();
            String familyName = person.getFamilyName();

            String queryString = "INSERT INTO persons (given_name, family_name) VALUES (" + givenName + " , " + familyName +" );";
            Connector connector = null;
            try {
                connector = Connector.getInstance();
                connector.executeQuery(queryString);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Here's the service method, that does the POST, using JAX-RS

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void addPerson(Person person){

        TeacherService.addPerson(person);
    }
```

The issue is that the object is not getting posted, as in the row is not being saved in the database.

Comment: One problem I see is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36482730/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO persons (given_name, family_name) VALUES (" + givenName + " , " + familyName +" );";
```

As peeskillet mentioned, the problem are the quotes. The code Java generates is for example:

```
-- From your code:
INSERT INTO persons (given_name, family_name) VALUES (MyName , MyLastname );
-- Should be:
INSERT INTO persons (given_name, family_name) VALUES ('MyName' , 'MyLastname' );
```

So your Java code becomes:

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO persons (given_name, family_name) VALUES ('" + givenName + "' , '" + familyName +"' );";
```

However I do recommend to use Prepared Statements (or Parameterized Queries) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).